# Unit Testing a little function that only use a framework method

Tags: unit-testing

In my code (scala) I have this little function that reads CSV files from a directory using Spark & Zio:

```
def readCsv[T <: Product: TypeTag](
      path: String, delimiter: String = ",", header: String = "true")(implicit encoder: Encoder[T], sparkSession: SparkSession): Dataset[T] =
    sparkSession.read
          .options(Map("delimiter"->delimiter, "header"->header))
          .csv(path)
          .as[T]
```

My goal is to make a generic reader to customize some parameters, here the delimiter and the header.

I made a small unit test to check if my function return a valid and non empty dataset.

The issue here is that my collegue told me that it is not necessary and completely useless to make this unit test because we are only using a Spark framework function.

I'm totally agreee with this but, as soon as I'v created a new function into my project and this function takes parameters, I must test it with different cases.

Do any pro (or not) developer have an opinion on this?

Thnx